# Markdown keyboard in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, ios-app

When entering text in a textview that supports Markdown input (such as when asking a question), the keyboard should have a toolbar (an `inputAccessoryView`) that shows characters common for markdown input.  At the very least, <kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>, <kbd>(</kbd>, <kbd>)</kbd>, <kbd>#</kbd> and <kbd>*</kbd> should be added.  Maybe <kbd>-</kbd>, and even <kbd><kbd></kbd>.

Optional: if you're concerned about screen space, you could limit this to iPhones with 4" (or larger) screens.

This would make it way easier to add/edit code blocks and formatting.

[image: Mockup of iOS app with Markdown keyboard]

---

**EDIT**: Updated image (based on feedback in comments) to use red freehand drawing instead of orange.

Comment: Honestly it should probably have a different layout per site; `stackoverflow` needs one, `math.se` needs a different one (to use the fancy math stuff).

Comment: I agree that certain sites should be able to customize it down the road, but markdown is a great default
 for all sites

Comment: I'm fairly new to meta, but I was under the impression all freehand drawing is to be done in **red**, not **orange**. What is this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm colorblind. It looks red to me

Comment: I can update the image. What's the correct RGB value?

Comment: `(255, 0, 0)`, but it's all tongue in cheek of course

Comment: @mhlester Updated.

Comment: see, now i feel bad. the orange was growing on me. it could have been the start of a new chapter

Comment: @mhlester If you look carefully you can still see the orange underneath.

Comment: I've gotten very good at accessing these characters from my iPad and iPhone soft keyboards. I might just be a power user, though.

Comment: @undo I'm pretty fast too, but 
it's 3 taps to type [, and another 3 for ].  You could type them at the same time but then you have to move the cursor back. Typing ` requires a long-press and a drag.  One tap would be way easier.

Comment: Absolutely. I just have gotten used to and become efficient at typing markdown from my iPad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a planned feature. It most likely won't be implemented until post-beta (public launch). Currently you can do some minor things by highlighting the text and selecting it from the pop-up, but actual buttons for them above the keyboard are planned too.

Comment: `THAT'S GREAT NEWS

Answer (score 8):

Post-beta? Kasra is such a pessimist.  A formatting toolbar will be in the next build.

> [image]

Comment: I have to chuckle you masked the image as spoiler, when that's something that doesn't work in the app!

Comment: @mhlester Fixed in the next build. :)

Comment: Shneaky shneaky!

Comment: Scotty taught me to under promise and over deliver.