# Wiki formatting help in android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I would like to suggest that the android app have a button or menu option to provide help with the wiki formatting codes on the post editor. Sometimes I forget many of the codes needed to make formatting.

And even if I do remember certain codes, some of them may be difficult to enter on my phone--for example, I don't think my android keyboard has a backtick key to make `code samples`, so the formatting help would be even better if it included a way to add needed special characters as well.

Comment: [Related, but in no way a dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222315/markdown-keyboard-in-ios-app)

Comment: With the variety of keyboard apps and having (or not) physical keyboards on android, I would hope for a android-centric solution. My keyboard app has text-prediction, so the keyboard with prediction bar already takes up over half the screen--there would be little room left to see what I typed if another row got squished on top of the keyboard that you can't scroll off the screen.

Comment: As a developer who prefers back-end things, I will happily advise you to buy a phone with a bigger screen if that becomes an issue. :p