# Markdown right bracket doesn't advance cursor

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Using the ios app, the new markdown keyboard has [ ] buttons which are very nice and helpful.  Except, the right bracket button places the bracket to the right of the cursor, which isn't terribly helpful.  Further, if you hit it again, it doesn't advance past it (which might make sense) but adds a new one.[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think it is on purpose, actually. E.g., it's a feature. I must admit I haven't yet found it very useful.

Comment: That would make sense if a second push advanced it.  If not, though, it's a big pain - means you have to tap in the text area to leave the bracket region, making it useless.

Comment: If it is on purpose of course I'm more than willing to make this a feature request :)

Comment: some people (not me!) like to type both sides at once so they always remember to match. maybe [whoever](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227022/248072) implemented this feature is one of *those people*?

Comment: Again - I don't mind that, so long as a second keypress completes the bracket [although really the right way to do it is to initially supply the close bracket automatically].  I just don't want to have to tap the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  For context, this was built on top of other markdown editor code, so if you select a block of text and tap <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> the selection will be encapsulated with brackets.  Now if the selection is empty it just advances.